# Load/import an old wordpress website without export file

Tags: wordpress

I have an old wordpress website that I am trying to load. I cannot find an exported file. Basically, I had saved the entire xampp and wordpress directories, so I have all of those files. They were last modified in September 2011, which I believe is wordpress 3.2.1

I cannot seem to load them as I had reformatted that computer, and I mistakenly thought that copying and backing up the entire directory will properly backup my website (I think I forgot to create an export file).

Is there anything I can do to salvage this old website I last worked on in 2011?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little unclear however it sounds like you no longer have access to the original database, and you also don't have a backup of the database(ex: export file, sql backup.

If this is the case then, no, you cannot get your old content back.

You do still have a theme and a copy of an old version of Wordpress but all your posts and associated data are gone.

Comment: Thank you yes you are correct I upvoted your comment thanks again.